# IF dentro do while PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, if, while

Estou listando alguns resultados dentro do while meu objetivo é que quando alguma das variáveis que listo no while vierem vazias, ele listar só as que vierem com conteúdo.

ps. é um sistema de enquete, coloquei pra cadastrar 4 respostas, mas algumas perguntas tem apenas sim ou não como respostas, por isso quero listar apenas as que variáveis que vierem com conteúdo, segue o código abaixo:

```
<?

      $consulta = "SELECT * FROM perguntas ORDER BY id ASC   " ;
      $resultado_consulta = mysql_query($consulta) or die("Erro no SQL: ".mysql_error());
    while($lista = mysql_fetch_array($resultado_consulta)){

    $id = anti_injection($lista['id']);
    $validacao_campo = anti_injection($lista['$validacao_campo']);
    $pergunta_principal = anti_injection($lista['$pergunta_principal']);
    $primeira_opcao = anti_injection($lista['$primeira_opcao']);
    $segunda_opcao = anti_injection($lista['$segunda_opcao']);
    $terceira_opcao = anti_injection($lista['$terceira_opcao']);
    $quarta_opcao = anti_injection($lista['$quarta_opcao']);

     ?>


    <fieldset>
        <br>
        <h2 class="fs-title"> <?php echo $lista['pergunta_principal']; ?> </h2>
        <br>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>

        </fieldset>

        <?php

if (!empty("$lista['primeira_opcao'];")){
echo"<?php echo $lista['primeira_opcao']; ?> <input type='radio' value='<?php echo $lista['primeira_opcao']; ?>' 
name='<?php echo $lista['validacao_campo']; ?>'> ";
}
if (!empty("$lista['$segunda_opcao'];")){
echo"<?php echo $lista['segunda_opcao']; ?> <input type='radio' value='<?php echo $lista['segunda_opcao']; ?>' 
name='<?php echo $lista['validacao_campo']; ?>'>";
}
if (!empty("$lista['$terceira_opcao'];")){
echo"<?php echo $lista['terceira_opcao']; ?> <input type='radio' value='<?php echo $lista['terceira_opcao']; ?>'
 name='<?php echo $lista['validacao_campo']; ?>'>";
 }
if (!empty("$lista['$quarta_opcao'];")){
echo"<?php echo $lista['quarta_opcao']; ?> <input type='radio' value='<?php echo $lista['quarta_opcao']; ?>' 
name='<?php echo $lista['validacao_campo']; ?>'>";
}
endif;
?>

        <br><br>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Anterior" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Proxima" />
    </fieldset>

    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: E o problema é qual?

Comment: tá dando erro na hora de exibir,

Comment: acho que é na montagem final.. vou editar o código na pergunta que foi errado.

Comment: Qual erro é? poderia editar a pergunta com ele.

Comment: Postando um minuto

Comment: Onde edito minha postagem ?

Comment: Em baixo daquele quadrinho azul(php, if, while) tem o link do editar, pro código ficar formatado selecione ele e aperte no botão `{ }`

Comment: Clique em [edit]

Comment: ta editado, ficou melhor para que vejam ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remova as aspas e o ponto e virgula dentro desses if's:

```
!empty("$lista['primeira_opcao'];")
```

Para que ele fique assim:

```
!empty($lista['primeira_opcao'])
```

Nos seus echo's, vc esta imprimindo tudo errado.
Mude:

```
echo "<?php echo $lista['primeira_opcao']; ?> <input type='radio' value='<?php echo $lista['primeira_opcao']; ?>' name='<?php echo $lista['validacao_campo']; ?>'> ";
```

Para:

```
echo $lista['primeira_opcao'] . "<input type='radio' value='" . $lista['primeira_opcao'] . "' name='" . $lista['validacao_campo'] . "'> ";
```

Comment: deu certo só que só fica mostrando o primeiro echo.. sendo que quero que ele olhe nos quatro a variavel que vem vazia não aparece, só aparece a que vem.. no caso do meu teste, passei um com quatro valores.. só listou o primeiro alexandre

Comment: Resolvido essa dúvida obrigado a todos!

Comment: Voce tem que fazer essas alteracoes para todos os valores.